# Demonstration of relation between Major index and Inversion Number of Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

*Combinatorics of permutations by Miklos Bona* says that:

> In 1916, MacMahon showed the following surprising theorem by proving that the two relevant generating functions were identical. It was not until 1968 that **a bijective proof** was found by D. Foata, who worked in a more general setup.
>
> $\mathbf{\text{THEOREM 2.16}}$
> For all postive integers $n$ and all nonneative integers $k$, there are as many $n$-permutations with $k$ inversions as there are $n$-permutations with major index $k$.

---

They have same G.F.

$$
(1+x)(1+x+x^2)\cdots (1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1-x^i}{1-x}
$$

Actually, the sequence is [A008302](http://oeis.org/A008302).

---

I'm focusing on the bijective proof.
I found some articles about it:

- [ON THE NETTO INVERSION NUMBER OF A SEQUENCE](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1968-019-01/S0002-9939-1968-0223256-9/S0002-9939-1968-0223256-9.pdf)
- [Major index and Inverison Number of Permutations](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eberstel/Mps/Travaux/A/1978-3MajorIndexMathNachr.pdf)

**Is there any programming project/code snippet that demonstrates the algorithm** mentioned in *Major index and Inverison Number of Permutations*?

I wrote one Mathematica code snippet to demonstrate it, **can you give a faster implementation(in another language, e.g. Rust) for large $n$ ?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't find that, so I implement one. ✅

**Can you give a faster implementation(in another language, e.g. Rust) for large $n$ ?**

```
TransformPhi[s_List] := Module[{n, w, splitAndMove}, n = Length[s];
  w[1] = {s[[1]]};
  splitAndMove[list_, value_, compFunc_] := 
   Module[{positions, segments}, 
    positions = Flatten[Position[list, _?compFunc]];
    If[Length[positions] == 0, Return[{list}]];
    positions = {0}~Join~positions;
    segments = 
     Table[list[[(positions[[i - 1]] + 1) ;; positions[[i]]]], {i, 2, 
       Length[positions]}];
    Join @@ (RotateRight[#, 1] & /@ segments)];
  Do[If[Last[w[k - 1]] > s[[k]], 
     w[k] = Join[
       splitAndMove[w[k - 1], s[[k]], # > s[[k]] &], {s[[k]]}], 
     w[k] = Join[
       splitAndMove[w[k - 1], s[[k]], # < s[[k]] &], {s[[k]]}]];
   , {k, 2, n}];
  w[n]]

(*Test*)
TransformPhi[{7, 4, 9, 2, 6, 1, 5, 8, 3}]
```

```
TransformPhiInverse[inputv_List] := 
 Module[{n, s, v, splitAndMove}, n = Length[inputv];
  s[n] = Last[inputv];
  v[n - 1] = Most[inputv];
  splitAndMove[list_, value_, compFunc_] := 
   Module[{positions, segments, breakPts}, 
    positions = Flatten[Position[list, _?compFunc]] - 1;
    If[Length[positions] == 0, Return[{list}]];
    breakPts = Append[1 + positions, Length[list] + 1];
    segments = 
     Table[list[[breakPts[[i]] ;; breakPts[[i + 1]] - 1]], {i, 
       Length[breakPts] - 1}];
    Join @@ (RotateLeft[#, 1] & /@ segments)
    ];
  Do[
   If[v[k][[1]] > s[k + 1], 
    v[k - 1] = splitAndMove[v[k], s[k + 1], # > s[k + 1] &],
    v[k - 1] = splitAndMove[v[k], s[k + 1], # < s[k + 1] &]];
   s[k] = Last[v[k - 1]];
   If[k >= 2, v[k - 1] = Drop[v[k - 1], -1]];
   , {k, n - 1, 1, -1}
   ];
  
  Array[s, n]
  ]

(*Test*)
TransformPhiInverse[{6, 4, 9, 7, 2, 5, 8, 1, 3}]
```

```
n = 5;
MajorIndex[perm_List] := 
  Sum[If[perm[[i]] > perm[[i + 1]], i, 0], {i, Length[perm] - 1}];
InversionNumber[perm_List] := 
  Length[Select[Subsets[Range[Length[perm]], {2}], 
    perm[[#[[1]]]] > perm[[#[[2]]]] &]];
permutations = Permutations[Range[n]];



MajorIndex /@ permutations // Tally // Sort
InversionNumber /@ permutations // Tally // Sort


(InversionNumber@*TransformPhi) /@ permutations // Tally // Sort
(MajorIndex@*TransformPhi) /@ permutations // Tally // Sort
((InversionNumber@*TransformPhi@# - MajorIndex@#) &) /@ permutations


(InversionNumber@*TransformPhiInverse) /@ permutations // Tally // Sort
(MajorIndex@*TransformPhiInverse) /@ permutations // Tally // Sort
((MajorIndex@*TransformPhiInverse@# - InversionNumber@#) &) /@ permutations
```